# MVC- receive selected Dropdownlist value in [HttpPost] method on change event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

Hey..
How to receive selected Dropdownlist value in [HttpPost] method on change event? I always receive it in [HttpGet] method.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipTpa, ViewData[ArtikliKonstante.vdListaTipovaTPa] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                new { onchange = "location.href='/Artikli/PromjenaTipa? p='+this.value"})%>
```

If I declare my method as [HttpPost] I get error, that action doesn't exist. Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to POST if you want the proper action to be invoked. In your case you are simply redirecting (window.location.href) which sends a GET request.

So you could place the dropdown inside a form and use javascript to submit the form when the selection changes:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("PromjenaTipa", "Artikli", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" })) { %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.TipTpa, 
        ViewData[ArtikliKonstante.vdListaTipovaTPa] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
        new { id = "tipTpa" }
    ) %>
<% } %>
```

and then subscribe for the change event in javascript (example with jquery):

```
$(function() {
    $('tipTpa').change(function() {
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
});
```

This will POST the form to the `PromjenaTipa` action where you could read the selected value:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PromjenaTipa(string tipTpa)
{
    // tipTpa should contain the selected value
    ...
}
```

Another possibility would be to send an AJAX query in the change event. In this case you don't need a form as you could send POST request with AJAX.